# How to implement thread-safe LRU cache eviction?

Tags: c++, multithreading, caching, lru

I've implemented an LRU cache ([code](https://github.com/sweeneychris/TheiaSfM/blob/master/src/theia/util/lru_cache.h)) that I would like to use for a multithreaded matching problem with N elements and full N^2 (all pairs) matching. Ideally, I would just get a reference to each element directly from the cache to save memory.

The time is takes to match two elements (lets call them A and B) can greatly vary, and I am worried that if one pair of elements takes a long time to match then another thread (that is working very fast and processing many pairs) will cause either A or B to be evicted from the cache, making the references invalid.

A simple solution is to just not use references, but I'm wondering if there is a better way to ensure that elements won't be evicted if they are "currently used" or have a reference to them?

Comment: Your question is impossible to answer without any information about your key and value types. An obvious approach is to store and give out `std::shared_ptr` - but to answer who should create them, when, etc. requires more information.

Comment: Also, your whole class is not thread safe. So it will likely crash regardless of your concern about eviction. So you should start with protecting critical sections with mutexes (or whatever synchronization approach you prefer).

Comment: Yes, I know it is not currently thread-safe. This question came up to me when starting to add thread-safety.

Comment: And I actually disagree about the key/value part. I am asking if there is any insight to a general solution since this is a general LRU cache

Comment: For general key/value types the only possible way to make code thread safe is to use locking when access map `cache_entries_map_`. But if you apply some restrictions on types used(e.g., `atomic<>` type for value, *integer* type for key), I guess it would be possible to use some special implementation of map, which doesn't use locking(that is, become *lock-free*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid evicting objects that are in use it is possible to use the reference-counting functionality of `std::shared_ptr`. Consider the following implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename K, typename V> class cache
{
public:
    cache() {}

    static const constexpr int max_cache_size = 2;

    std::shared_ptr<V> getValue(const K& k)
    {
        auto iter = cached_values.find(k);
        if (iter == cached_values.end()) {

            if (cached_values.size() == max_cache_size) {
                auto evictIter =
                    std::find_if(cached_values.begin(), cached_values.end(),
                        [](const auto& kv) { return kv.second.second.unique(); });

                if (evictIter == cached_values.end()) {
                    std::cout << "Nothing to evict\n";
                    return nullptr;
                }

                cached_values.erase(evictIter);
            }

            static V next;

            iter = cached_values.insert(std::make_pair(k, std::make_pair(++next, nullptr))).first;
            iter->second.second = std::shared_ptr<V>(&iter->second.first, [](const auto&) {});
        }

        return iter->second.second;
    }

    std::map<K, std::pair<V, std::shared_ptr<V>>> cached_values;
};

int main()
{
    cache<int, int> c;

    std::cout << *c.getValue(10) << "\n";
    std::cout << *c.getValue(20) << "\n";
    std::cout << *c.getValue(30) << "\n";

    auto useOne = c.getValue(10);
    auto useTwo = c.getValue(20);
    std::cout << *c.getValue(20) << "\n"; // We can use stuff that is still in cache
    std::cout << c.getValue(30);          // Cache is full, also note no dereferencing
}
```

Basically, as long as anyone outside the cache uses the returned value, the `std::shared_ptr::unique` will return false, making the cache entry non-evictable.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fb55fa4768dcd215)

Comment: Thanks very much. You're definitely correct about `std::shared_ptr` being the right thing to use. Luckily, with my implementation above I can just pass the shared_ptr as the templated value